# best way to use LINQ to query against a list

Tags: c#, linq

i have a collection

```
IEnumerable<Project>
```

and i want to do a filter based on project's Id property to included any id that is in a list:

```
List<int> Ids
```

what is the best way to do a where clause to check if a property is contained in a list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var filteredProjectCollection = projectCollection.Where(p => Ids.Contains(p.id));
```

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to get a more efficient implementation using the `Except` method:

```
var specialProjects = Ids.Select(id => new Project(id));
var filtered = projects.Except(specialProjects, comparer);
```

The tricky thing is that `Except` works with two collections of the same type - so you want to have two collections of projects. You can get that by creating new "dummy" projects and using `comparer` that compares projects just based on the ID.

Alternatively, you could use `Except` just on collections of IDs, but then you may need to lookup projects by the ID, which makes this approach less appealing.

Answer (score 1):

`var nonExcludedProjects = from p in allprojects where Ids.Contains(p => p.Id) select p;`

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use one of the .Where(p=> list.Contains(p)) answers, you should consier first making a HashSet out of the list so that it doesn't have to do an O(n) search each time.  This cuts running time from O(mn) to O(m+n).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand your question but I'll have a shot.

If you have: IEnumerable enumerable,
and you want to filter it such that it only contians items that are also present in the list: List list,
then: IEnumerable final = enumerable.Where(e => list.Contains(e));